# Add direct labels to ggplot2 geom_area chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a continuation of the question here: [Create non-overlapping stacked area plot with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393269/create-non-overlapping-stacked-area-plot-with-ggplot2)

I have a ggplot2 area chart created by the following code. I want the labels from `names` be aligned on the right side of the graph. I think `directlabels` might work, but am willing to try whatever is most clever.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plyr)
require(RColorBrewer)
require(RCurl)
require(directlabels)

link <- getURL("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25609375/so_data/final.txt")
dat <- read.csv(textConnection(link), sep=' ', header=FALSE, 
         col.names=c('count', 'name', 'episode'))


dat <- ddply(dat, .(episode), transform, percent = count / sum(count))

# needed to make geom_area not freak out because of missing value
dat2 <- rbind(dat, data.frame(count = 0, name = 'lane',
                             episode = '02-tea-leaves', percent = 0))

g <- ggplot(arrange(dat2,name,episode), aes(x=episode,y=percent)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=name, group = name), position='stack') + scale_fill_brewer()

g1 <- g + geom_dl(method='last.points', aes(label=name))
```

[image]

I'm brand new to `directlabels` and not really sure how to get the labels to align to right side of the graph with the same colors as the areas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use simple `geom_text` to add labels. First, subset you data set to get the final x value:

```
dd=subset(dat, episode=="06-at-the-codfish-ball")
```

Then order the data frame by factor level:

```
dd = dd[with(dd, order(name, levels(dd$name))),]
```

Then work out the cumulative percent for plotting:

```
dd$cum = cumsum(dd$percent)
```

Then just use a standard `geom_text` call:

```
g + geom_text(data=dd, aes(x=6, y=cum, label=name))
```

Oh, and you may want to angle your x-axis labels to avoid over plotting:

```
g + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-25, hjust=0.5, size = 8))
```

**Graph**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to figure out directlabels, cause I don't know how general-izable this approach is.

Comment: @csgillespie, This was useful thanks. Here the syntax I used (another df): ``+ geom_text(data = subset(df, Year == "2012"), aes(x = Year, y = cumsum(value), label = variable), vjust = 6, hjust = -.2, size = 4)``, where I found it fiddly to get the ``vjust`` and ``hjust`` parameters right. I'm saying it to emphasize that you can pass ``cumsum`` to the ``aes()``, which I discovered by trial and error. For the legend on the right, it's useful to set ``+ guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))`` to get the colours in the same order as the image. Do you want to update the deprecated ``opts``?

Comment: And to catch the last element of the dataframe (``06-at-the-codfish-ball`` in the OP and ``2012`` in my comment above), you can use the ``tail()`` function with argument `1`, e.g. ``tail(df2.1$Year, 1)``