# make a Stacked Area Graph In ggplot2

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, area, stacked-area-chart

I know there are already some severel questions about this theme, but i still can't get mine to work.

I have this data.frame of some Standard Deviation

```
df_sd_ <- data.frame(data = c("Oct","Nov","Dec","Jan"), 
                       Rent = c(2.84,0.87,1.03,1.31),
                       Ibov = c(3.64,2.42,1.62,2.03), 
                       NTNB = c(1.61,1.25,1.58,0.64))
```

And i need to plot a stacked area chart, similar to this:

[image]

Comment: could someone help me?

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you show the attempts that you've made so far and briefly explain how they are not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create non-overlapping stacked area plot with ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393269/create-non-overlapping-stacked-area-plot-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from R graphics cookbook.

```
Library(ggplot2)
library(gcookbook)

head(uspopage)

ggplot(uspopage, aes(x=Year, y=Thousands, fill=AgeGroup)) + geom_area()
```

then you will get something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My humble advice - you should make your data (df_sd_) tidy first, and then put it to ggplot. Read about and then use pivot_longer function.

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.