# R: error in ggplot:argument "env" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Shiny newbie here.

I am trying to write a R shiny script, and one of things I want to do is generate various plots.
I have a written this code for plotting by taking input from user but getting error of

```
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Need Help to solve this
   I am uploading my server and ui code.

```
 Server.r      


 shinyServer(function(input,output){
      data<-reactive({
        file1<-input$file
        if(is.null(file1)){return()}
        read.table(file=file1$datapath,sep = input$sep,header = input$header,stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
      })
        output$variable <- renderUI({ 
            obj<-data()   
            if (is.null(obj)) 
              return(NULL)
            var.opts<-namel(colnames(obj))
            selectInput("variable","Variable:", var.opts)                
          })
          # y variable
          output$group <- renderUI({ 
            obj<-data()   
            if (is.null(obj)) 
              return(NULL)
            var.opts<-namel(colnames(obj))
            selectInput("group","Groups:", var.opts)                 
          })
          #caption
          output$caption<-renderText({
            switch(input$plot.type,
                   "boxplot"   =    "Boxplot",
                   "histogram" =    "Histogram",
                   "density"    =   "Density plot",
                   "bar"        =   "Bar graph")
          })
          #plot
          output$plot <- renderUI({
            plotOutput("p")
          })
          #plotting function using ggplot2
          output$p <- renderPlot({
            obj<-data()
            plot.type<-switch(input$plot.type,
                              "boxplot"   =     geom_boxplot(),
                              "histogram" = geom_histogram(alpha=0.5,position="identity"),
                              "density"     =   geom_density(alpha=.75),
                              "bar"         =   geom_bar(position="dodge")
            )

            require(ggplot2)
            #plotting theme
            .theme<- theme(
              axis.line = element_line(colour = 'gray', size = .75), 
              panel.background = element_blank(),  
              plot.background = element_blank()
            )   


            if(input$plot.type=="boxplot")  {       #control for 1D or 2D graphs 
              p<-ggplot(data=obj, 
                        aes(
                          x         = obj$group, 
                          y         = obj$variable,
                          fill  = as.factor(obj$group)
                        )
              ) + plot.type

              if(input$show.points==TRUE)
              { 
                p<-p+ geom_point(color='black',alpha=0.5, position = 'jitter')
              }

            } else {

              p<-ggplot(data=obj, 
                        aes(
                          x         = obj$variable,
                          fill  = as.factor(obj$group),
                          group     = as.factor(obj$group)
                          #color    = as.factor(plot.obj$group)
                        )
              ) + plot.type
            }

            p<-p+labs(
              fill  = input$group,
              x         = "",
              y         = input$variable
            )  +
              .theme
            print(p)
          }) 
    })
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  #Heading panel
  titlePanel(title="Machine Learning and Statistics",),
  #input data set
  sidebarLayout(position = "right",
                sidebarPanel(fileInput('file', 'Choose a File', multiple = T, accept=c('text/csv', 
                                                                                       'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                                                                       '.csv')),
                             #default size for dataset
                             helpText("Default max. size is 7mb"),
                             #input number of observations
                             numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10),

                             tags$hr(),
                             checkboxInput(inputId = 'header',label = 'Header',value = TRUE),
                             checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors","stringAsFactors",TRUE),
                             br(),
                             radioButtons(inputId = 'sep',label = 'Seprator',choices=c(comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t',Space=' '),selected = ','),
                             sliderInput("train_percent",
                                         "Training Percentage:",
                                         min = 10, max = 90, 
                                         value = 20, step = 10),
                             uiOutput("variable"),   # depends on dataset ( set by output$variable in  server.R)
                             uiOutput("group"),     # depends on dataset    ( set by output$group in  server.R)
                             selectInput("plot.type","Plot Type:", 
                                         list(boxplot = "boxplot", histogram = "histogram", density = "density", bar = "bar")
                             ),
                             checkboxInput("show.points", "show points", TRUE)


                ),
                mainPanel(
                  ("output"),
                  h3(textOutput("caption")),
                  uiOutput("plot")
)
)))
```

Help?Thanks.

Comment: Could you have an [empty data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27568172/2461552)?

Comment: Not sure whether this is causing it, but inside your `aes` calls, I think you may need to use the variable names itself instead of dollar notation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this error message when using `ggplot` in Shiny is:

```
ggplot(data = obj, aes(...), environment = environment())
```

Would appreciate if someone could explain the reason behind the extra need for this in a Shiny app.

Comment: The variables insides aes(...) is evaluated at the global scope, when calling a ggplot within a function,  the environment has to be redefined with environment = environment(), see:  https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/743